# Using a variable as an index for a list

Tags: python

Can't find a way around this anywhere else.
Using Python 3.7

```
rowNum = input
row = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
print(row[rowNum])
```

This is an overly simplified example of my program.
Basically all i want to do is make it so that i can use whatever value is entered into "rowNum" as the index. I'm getting "Keyerror : *Number inputted*"
Not sure how to fix.
(I am relativley new to this site so excuse me for bad formatting if any)

Comment: `input` is a built-in function, not a number

Comment: Did you mean `rowNum = input()`? (Or rather `rowNum = int(input())`?)

Comment: @Aran-Fey The "input" text is semi psuedo becasue it is an input from a dropdown of another section of my program. (I am using tkinter drop-downs)

Comment: We need a proper [mcve] if we are to help you. We can't guess what is wrong with your input that it doesn't work

Comment: @UnholySheep The value for rowNum is a counter from a for loop i have earlier in my program, i just used "input" to show that the value is not always the same.

Comment: Pseudocode is bad. We need a real [mcve]. It's completely impossible for the code you posted to throw a KeyError, so consequently it's impossible to say what you did wrong.

Answer (score 3):

```
rowNum = int(input())
row = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
print(row[rowNum])
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to actually grab the user input:

```
rowNum = int(input("Enter a row number: "))
row = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
print(row[rowNum])
```

Convert it to an integer, a list will not take a string. Here is your output:

```
Enter a row number: 4
5
```